# Multiple push notifications by one post request via google FCM api

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

To sending push notification messages via google FCM api currently I use postman with a json syntax like this:

```
{
  "condition":"my condition",
  "notification":{
     "title" : "the title",
     "body":"the body"
  }
}
```

and it is ok. and if I need to send 2 messages so I have to send messages separately by 2 post call. like this:

```
{
  "condition":"my condition",
  "notification":{
     "title" : "the title 1",
     "body":"the body 1"
  }
}
```

---> pressing send button

```
{
  "condition":"my condition",
  "notification":{
     "title" : "the title 2",
     "body":"the body 2"
  }
}
```

---> pressing send button

and is ok too. but the problem is I have 2 network overheads for sending this messages.
Is there any syntax to send multiple messages by one post request?
I read and I know about the sending to multiple devices and so on... that is not my problem. my problem is : sending 2 or more messages in one post request.

Answer (score 0):

The FCM SDK has an option for [batching requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages) which will let you group messages into a single batch and send them im a single call. For REST request, you can make a list of sub requests:

```
--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"FCM Message",
       "body":"This is an FCM notification message to device 0!"
     }
  }
}

--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST /v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
  "message":{
     "topic":"readers-club",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Price drop",
       "body":"2% off all books"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: By this method we have multiple posts In the background so we have multiple network overhead.